# Redux - returning an array instead of an object in the reducer

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I'm trying to make a change on a page, once addListItem is ran an array called "list" that is actually a redux state, needs to be updated. I managed to update it, but instead of an array I return an object. I need to return an array instead, but I don't know how to refactor the code to make it do that.

```js
/**
 * Add Item
 */
case 'playlist/addListItem_success': {
  return {
    ...state,
    list: {
      ...state.list,
      [action.meta.position]: {
        ...state.list[action.meta.position],
        status: true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To return an array, you'd have to use the array-spread syntax (e.g. `[...someArray]`) instead of object spread, but you can't use that to update a particular index. With a `map` you can elegantly express what you need though:

```
return {
  ...state,
  list: state.list.map((e, i) => i === action.meta.position ? {...e, status: true} : e)
};
```